# Elasticsearch: Find the indices of the text that matches with your query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am fairly new to Elasticsearch!
I have a series of short documents and I have indexed them.
Now, I want to use Elasticsearch to find some words in the documetns along with their position

For example, this is a record "this is a test record"
I want to find the position of "test" in this string

for example : start_index = 10
end_index = 13

I have figured out how to retrieve "test" with the match query.
my first question is: what should my search query look like?
and my second question is: where should I have specificaaly read so I could have had found the answer on my won?